# Actualizar varios campos utilizando mysql y php

Tags: php, mysql

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: Estoy haciendo una consulta a la base de datos, tomando datos como nombre de producto, precio del producto, etc. y de esos valores de la consulta a la base de datos quiero hacer un `update` a otra tabla.

```
$mysql="select pedidos.id_pedido,detalle_pedidos.id_detalle_pedidos,detalle_pedidos.id_pedido,detalle_pedidos.id_producto,detalle_pedidos.cantidad_producto,productos.nombre_producto,productos.precio_producto,productos.cantidad 
FROM((pedidos 
  INNER JOIN detalle_pedidos ON pedidos.id_pedido=detalle_pedidos.id_pedido) 
  INNER JOIN productos ON productos.id_producto=detalle_pedidos.id_producto) 
WHERE pedidos.id_pedido='$clavepedido";

$resultado=$bd->consultar($mysql);

foreach ($resultado as $row) {
  $clavepedido=$row['id_pedido'];
  $clave_detalle_pedido=$row['id_detalle_pedidos'];
  $clave_producto=$row['id_producto'];
  $qty_pedido=$row['cantidad_producto'];
  $nameprod=$row['nombre_producto'];
  $price=$row['precio_producto'];
  $qty_db=$row['cantidad'];
  $cal_comision=$price*0.1;

  $update="update detalle_pedidos 
           set nombre_producto='".$row['nombre_producto']."',
               precio_producto='".$row['precio_producto']."' 
           where id_detalle_pedidos='".$row['id_detalle_pedidos']."'";
  $res=$resultado=$bd->insertar($update);
}
```

No se si estoy realizando de manera correcta el `update`. Agradecería cualquier sugerencia o ayuda.

Comment: Muestra más código. Una cosa que llama la atención es: Estas usando un método llamado `$bd->insertar()`. Me imagino que esa función inserta. No necesitas una que se llame `actualizar()`?  Pon el código de `insertar`. Otra cosa no veo necesario ` $res=$resultado=$bd-...` no sería mejor... `$res=$bd->actualizar($update);` Muestra el código de insertar .

Comment: Creo que en cuanto a lo que dices @EduardPinuaga de `$bd->insertar()` se refiere a la clase donde hace la conexión a mysql que sería `$bd` donde la instancia, y en esta clase es donde hace los metodos para consultar o ejecutar una `query` por lo tanto el `insertar()` se refería a ejecutar una `query` ya sea un `insert, update o delete`

Comment: Ya ejecutaste esas consultas en phpMyAdmin o dónde estés administrando la base de datos?